# 2 different fetch requests in one grouped tableview (iOS)

Tags: ios, tableview

I've been working successfully with any tableviews. Now I want to display an overview from 1st fetchrequest in the first section of a grouped tableview. In the 2nd section should be shown a list of detailed informations.

Is it possible to display data in one and more data in a another tableview section?

I try to do this with static labels, for better understanding.

Should look like this screenshot - but I am a new user cant post images :(

Comment: you definitely can. Just don't use `NSFetchedResultsController` which will take care of setting up your table view. Do fetch requests manually and just handle them as normal.

Comment: You also can do this using `NSFetchedResultsController`, it is just not as easy. But it is still much easier than replicating all the functionality of the fetched results controller.

Comment: Means it 2 fetchrequests into arrays and then, each array in the specified sections with their number of elements as the number of rows?

Comment: How can I access the right section for the array with data belongs to the requested section?